# Where can I find Ubuntu Mate 16.04 ISO to install ROS Kinetic on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ros-master-uri, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use ROS Kinetic on a network with my PC and Raspberry PI. And to do so, I want to isntall ubuntu mate on my pi. But on the official website, they have removed the link to download ubuntu mate 16.04.
I tried installing melodic with mate 18.04, but have problems with rosserial on arduino. I get an error saying version mismatch as melodic has Rev 1 whereas kinetic has Rev0.

Can anyone provide me a link to the OS image?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330478/where-can-i-find-ubuntu-mate-16.04-iso-to-install-ros-kinetic-on-raspberry-pi/) by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on ROS Answers with karma: 463 on 2019-08-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-12-29**:
Please note that the error wasn't due to 18.04, it was because of low time delay in loop() of arduino code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/) website has the 16.04 image you are looking for.

You can find torrent files for older Ubuntu Mate releases [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/old-ubuntu-mate-releases-torrent-downloads-md5-checksums/19426). They are at the bottom of the post titled **Old Raspberry Pi releases**.

I would suggest the ones in the second link, but you can also use the first link too if you don't want to use a torrent.

---

Originally posted by [zmk5](https://answers.ros.org/users/44691/zmk5/) with karma: 71 on 2019-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1